# Keep parent hover state when child is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, parent-child

I've found multiple solutions that work but nothing seems to fix another problem this creates. When I add the CSS and jQuery code for doing this and I refresh my browser to see if it works, it does.....mostly. The background of the parent element keeps the hover state but the text fades back to its original, non-hovered state, leaving nothing but an orange (`#d35400`) background (because the text is originally that color but turns a white color [`#ecf0f1`] when the item is hovered over).

At this point I don't know what to do. I've tried 4-5 different solutions that get the parent element to keep its hover state but the text of the parent element just won't stay the color it's supposed to.

I would include the code here but I'm afraid it's not allowing me to because of how much I need to include. So here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmdunrzj/2/. Please hover over "Roster" (the second menu item from the left) and then hover over any of its drop-down items. The background keeps its hover state but the text won't. I've tried everything I can think of and none of what I try has helped (obviously).

I look forward to your responses and help! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/Lmdunrzj/5/)

I did not change anything in your code, all I did was include jQuery.2.1.4 and it seems to be working. This would lead me to believe you do not have jQuery resourced on your html page. If this does not fix your issue please let me know with more detail.

Here is the jquery resource:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: What I have linked in my `<head></head>` tags is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. All of my other jQuery scripts are working perfectly so there is definitely no problem there. That being said, I didn't realize there was a more updated version, so thanks nonetheless! Lol.

Comment: I removed the original link I had to jQuery 1.11.3 and replaced it with the one you provided for jQuery 2.1.4 and it works flawlessly now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: awesome! glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the hover state of the entire navigation item when hovering other sub-items if you set the `:hover` event to the `<li>` parent instead of the `<a>`-tag.

```
header div#nav-container nav#nav-menu ul#nav-items li.roster-li:hover > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

And you should probably not use that many id (or any) IDs in your CSS since it will make it much harder to overwrite styles.

Try to read up on specifity because it will speed up both development and page loads. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-specificity-irrelevant/

Comment: I'm self-taught so I just learn from what I read and hear and I've always been told to only use classes when there will be multiple elements needing the exact same styling but to use IDs if that's going to be the only element needing that specific styling. Is this not the case?

Also, I tried getting it to work with the change you suggested and I get the same result I was getting before. Thank you so much for the suggestion though!

Comment: Updated the answer with a more specific selector that should work better. Place it below the other `:hover` code in your css.